# Problem Escaping Special Character in JQL

Tags: escaping, jql

Having problem escaping special character in JQL in the guidelined manner.

Would like to get issues in specific conditions which include a comment with a special character in it, "#" in this case.

project in (A1, A2) AND status = "W1" AND assignee in (U1) AND comment ~ "#"

Answer (score -1):

I found this Jira ticket for your question:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-66244

If you are new to Jira and JQL -- the Atlassian documentation is the best possible source of information one can get.!

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Please post the contents of this link, as this link requires a login to the system, which not everybody is going to have.